# Using Ubuntu on SSD with a Separate Data Drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, directory, mv

I have been researching this for quite some time coming from Windows that there is no “Path” that you can give to a program during installation, but instead the program downloads where it needs to.

Is there a way on Linux based systems that instead of filling up/installing on the Main SSD (with the OS) the program installs on a separate data drive?

The only solution seems to move the home directory and some other directories? What are those other directories that would need to be moved and how would that be done? Would I mount them somewhere else or use `mv`?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What programs and how are you trying to install them?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to divert data to other volumes by symlinking systemfolders elsewhere. However, don't. Prefer to have the system reside on the SSD for 1) performance reasons and 2) because system and application files need relatively limited space overall, typically less than 25 GB.

Prefer to move user data that you use less frequently, or archive data, to other (eventually slower) media. Irrespective on what partition or folder data really reside, you can use symbolic links to have quick access from within your home folder.

For data to be accessible, the partition must be mounted. External drives are automatically mounted when you plug them in. Internal drives are only mounted when you click on them in the file manager. Alternatively, they must explicitly be configured to mount automatically during startup. The tool "Disks" can be used to configure that.

Symbolic links can easily be made using the file manager. In the "Preferences", you can set an option to include an item in the right-click menu for creating symbolic links.